# C++ String Matching Between Two different files

Tags: c++, string, string-matching

I have a really long .txt file to be read, and another that contains questions that may be changed from time to time, questions will be in the form of Wh- questions such as "Who.. , When.. , Why.. " in the file the answer is exactly after/before the question. For example, "Who stole the bread?" the answer in the file will be "Jerry stole the bread."
The output of the code should be in the manner of:
Q: Who stole the bread?
A: Jerry
I am having trouble thinking of a way to match strings from the file with the string in the question file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you tied hashing the strings and compare them?

Comment: Start with the matching, for a start. Create a function that given a sentence and an action tells you whether the sentence describes the action.

Comment: @Steback I read about it, since I am not that experienced, I did not want to over complicate it on myself. Any other ideas?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I did not quite understand, can you explain more please?

Comment: Create a function. If that puzzles you, please take a C++ tutorial. Name that function e.g. `match()`. Then, make sure you can call it with two strings, like `match("a", "b")` and that it returns a boolean values (e.g. `true`). Then, write some calls as tests and output their results. Then, work on the actual implementation of the function, so that it does what it should, like return `true` for `match("a b c", "b c")`. A different approach starts with making a human-language description, with that much detail that there is no question at all what each step means.